# Defining operators in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Having defined two operators in Prolog:

```
op(100, xfy, #).
op(100, fy, ϴ).
```

what is the expression

```
a # ϴ b # c
```

equivalent to?

```
a # ϴ (b # c)
```

or maybe

```
a # ((ϴ b) # c)
```

And why?

Comment: `#` is of type xfy, so it is right-associative, isn't it? Is it enough to interpret the mentioned expression as `a # ((ϴ b) # c)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see what Prolog will do with it using `write_canonical/1`:

```
?- op(100,xfy,#).
true.

?- op(100,fy,@).
true.

?- write_canonical(a # @ b # c).
#(a,@(#(b,c)))
true.
```

So, it appears that your first speculation is correct. The interpretation of `a # @ b # c` is `a # (@(b # c))`. The key comment in the [documentation for `op/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=op/3) bearing on this is:

> The `f` indicates the position of the functor, while `x` and `y` indicate the position of the arguments. `y` should be interpreted as "on this position a term with precedence lower or equal to the precedence of the functor should occur". 
>   For `x` the precedence of the argument must be strictly lower.

The use of `fy` results in the precedence grouping of `@(b # c)` rather than `(@b) # c`.